# Hold selected item in Drop Down php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to hold selected value of drop down while submitting form on onchange event of drop down.

This is my code

```
echo "<form method=\"post\">
<select name=\"Color\" OnChange=\"this.form.submit();\"> ";
    while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
       $value = $rec['name'];
       echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
       if($row['name'] == $_SESSION['name'])
         echo " selected";
    }
echo "</select> "?>
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to "hold selected value" ?

Comment: `selected` is an attribute of `option`.

Comment: i mean i am a beginner i dont know that much my aim is when user select a value from drop down page reloads then i want to show user selected value in drop down

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean, if you submit the form but an error is on the inputs you want to keep the selected option.

Then, try this:

```
echo "<form method=\"post\">
<select name=\"Color\" OnChange=\"this.form.submit();\"> ";

while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $value = $rec['name'];

    $selected = ( $value == $_SESSION['name'] ) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$value\"$selected>$value</option>";
    echo "</select> "?>
```

I however think that `$_SESSION['name']` should be `$_POST['name']`

Comment: still not work plz help me with this when i apply your code nothing happens

Comment: Yeah, that's a great comment. Let me get my glass ball and predict where the flaw is... please debug your code line for line and see where it goes wrong. For instance, try echoing `$_SESSION['name']`, `$_POST['name']` and `$value`. What do you get then?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `if($row['name'] == $_SESSION['name'])` // instead of $row use $rec,because you used in mysql_fetch_array.

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="Color" OnChange="this.form.submit();">
    <?
    while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($query))
       {
            $value = $rec['name'];
       ?>
        <option value="<?echo $value;?>" <?if($rec['name']==$_SESSION['name']){echo "selected;"}?>>$value</option>
       <?}?>
    </select>
</form>
```